# On IIS 7.5, can a classic ASP page share session variables with an ASP.NET application?

Tags: asp.net, session, asp-classic, iis-7.5

If you have seen my previous questions, you're aware that I'm in the process of updating some existing ASP pages, in an effort to move them from a Windows 2000 environment to a Windows server 2008 R2 environment.  One of the pages offers the end-user the ability to upload a file to be processed later.

I re-wrote the original page that handled the uploading, using ASP.Net's file upload object.  It works fine, but I'm running in to a snag when trying to integrate the new aspx pages in with the existing asp pages.  The new aspx pages live in a subdirectory of the main application, along with a few other asp pages, but in order for the asp.net pages to function, I had to use the "convert to application" option on on the folder.  When I did that, I think it broke the ability for the new aspx pages (and any other asp pages in the folder containing the aspx pages) to use the Session variables that the parent pages use.

I tried creating an application pool for the new folder's application, but that didn't make any difference.  I also changed the managed pipeline from Integrated to Classic, both on the parent folder and on this folder with the aspx pages, but that also doesn't appear to have made any difference.

If anyone can shed some light on this, I'd be very grateful.

The main asp files live in folder named "dcn".  There are several child folders in the "dcn" folder, many of which contain asp pages.  Asp pages in those folders continue to work correctly.  The folder which contains the aspx pages is called "CNAM", and it has now been converted to an application.  Any asp page in this folder no longer seems to see the session variables that are available to the other folders/pages.

Thanks in advance for any insights or suggestions regarding this.  Again, I really appreciate any assistance.

Mitchell

Answer (score 2):

[How to Share Session State Between Classic ASP and ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479313.aspx)